# Acquia Dev Desktop Export to archive

Tags: importing-exporting, acquia-dev-desktop

I'm a newbie, so please forgive me if this is a dumb question.

Exactly what files does the "Export to Drupal archive" feature of Dev Desktop actually back up? I have searched the web and didn't find anything that would answer this question.

My understanding, at this point, is that I need to export/backup the database and my Sites folder. PhpMyAdmin will do an export/backup of the database, but I have to manually copy & paste the Sites folder and fool with all the settings in phpMyAdmin. It would really be nice if the Export to Drupal archive does this with only one click .

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Dev Desktop are you using? I just opened version 2, and I don't see the option you are describing.

Comment: I am using version 2 as well. Click the More button at the bottom to get to Export to Drupal archive.

Comment: So..., why don't you try it?

Answer (score 1):

It does what you almost exactly described. **Export to Drupal archive...** creates a tar.gz file (tarball) with a backed up docroot folder (your drupal site code) & a .sql file (DB dump). This is everything you need to export your site to any host that runs MySQL/MariaDB & Apache/PHP